# In MacOS what is the keyboard shortcut to switch between applications in the same Desktop?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, workspace

I'm trying to switch between applications in the same desktop. Is there a shortcut that already exists? Else how do I setup a shortcut that helps me accomplish this?

Comment: Question is unclear - what do you consider a 'workspace', as that's not a recognised term? You mean Space, otherwise known as a Desktop? There is no shortcut to stay within any given Space. Cmd/tab doesn't respect Spaces. If you better define what you need to achieve, various methods might be suitable.

Comment: I mean 'Desktop'. Have edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

The shortcut to switch Applications is <kbd>CMD</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>, but this does switch between Spaces.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd> is the default keyboard shortcut for moving focus to the next active window. This stays within the current Desktop/Space.

> System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Keyboard > Move focus to active or next window

All of these strategies and more are discussed here:

> #### Restricting Command+tab options to only apps that are in the current space
>
> https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5668/restricting-commandtab-options-to-only-apps-that-are-in-the-current-space

Comment: Is there a way to remap `CMD` `Tab` to this behaviour?

Comment: CTRL-F4 is buggy in MacOS Monterey. If you switch from e.g. desktop 1 to desktop 2 using keyboard shortcut and then press ctrl-f4 it will switch you do desktop 1 and activate window from that desktop.

Comment: This works also in stage manager, CTRL+F4 switches between the apps in the same stage

Comment: @Trismegistos I think it is because the switch starts from the active app, if you change the screen without to activate an app in that screen it can happen